# How to remove XML nodes depending attribute value of other nodes

Tags: xslt, attributes, nodes

I have an XML looking like this:

```
  <pack>
    <titlesPacks>
      <StoryPack id="1111111">
        <value>A</value>
      </StoryPack>
      <StoryPack id="2222222">
        <value>F</value>
      </StoryPack>
    </titlesPacks>
    <referenceTable>
       <TitleReference id="1111111" />
       <TitleReference id="2222222" />
    </referenceTable>
  </pack>
```

I need to copy the xml file, but:

- delete `StoryPack` nodes where `value` node has specific value (A, B, C for example). This part is already OK
- delete 'TitleReference`nodes where`id`attribute value  is equal to`id    `attribute value of' StoryPack` nodes deleted above

I don't know how to do the second one: I tried with Key, but doesn't work:

My current XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:data="http://example.com/data" exclude-result-prefixes="data">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="titleId" match="StoryPack" use="@id"/>

    <!-- Values for which nodes must be deleted -->
    <data:data xmlns="">
        <value>A</value>
        <value>B</value>
        <value>C</value>
    </data:data>

    <xsl:variable name="values" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/data:data/value"/>


    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<!-- Delete nodes with specific values -->
    <xsl:template match="StoryPack[value = $values]"/>

<!-- Dlete nodes with id from specific values -->
<xsl:template match="TitleReference[StoryPack[key('titleId', @id)/value = $values]]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you for your help!

=============

Following @michael.hor257k answers : my source XML is a little more complex, that's probably why it doesn't work in my case:
The Xpath of value is deeper:
/Pack/titlesPacks/StoryPack/assets/TitleAssets/assets/StringAssetInfo/value
So I've done:

```
<xsl:template match="TitleReference[key('titleId', @id)/assets/TitleAssets/assets/StringAssetInfo[@attrId = '127']/value = $values]" />
```

but it doesn't work.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pack>
  <titlesPacks>
    <StoryPack id="1111111">
      <assets>
        <TitleAssets>
             <assets>
               <StringAssetInfo attrId="127">
                  <value>A</value>
               </StringAssetInfo>
             </assets>
        </TitleAssets>
      </assets>
     </StoryPack>
    </titlesPacks>
    <referenceTable>
     <ReferenceTable>
      <titlesReferences>
        <TitleReference id = "1111111"/>
      </titlesReferences>
     </ReferenceTable>
    </referenceTable>
</pack>
```

my need is to

- delete `StoryPack` where attribute `attrId` of `StringAssetInfo` = 127 and  `value` = A, or B... => Already OK
- delete `TitleReference` where `id` attribute value = `id` attribute value of deleted nodes above

Comment: You may need to show more (or all) of your XSLT, because at first sight the template you have shown should match. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamL7. Maybe you have other templates matching `element` that are taking priority over the one you have shown? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC edited with more infos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="titleId" match="StoryPack" use="@id"/>

<!-- Values for which nodes must be deleted -->
<xsl:variable name="values">
    <value>A</value>
    <value>B</value>
    <value>C</value>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Delete nodes with specific values -->
<xsl:template match="StoryPack[value = $values/value]"/>

<!-- Delete nodes with id from specific values -->
<xsl:template match="TitleReference[key('titleId', @id)/value = $values/value]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

I have simplified the variable definition, so it can work in this online demo:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuP9
- and also because it's simpler.

---

### Added:

In view of your updated XML structure, change:

```
<xsl:template match="StoryPack[value = $values/value]"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="StoryPack[.//value = $values/value]"/>
```

or (preferably) to:

```
<xsl:template match="StoryPack[assets/TitleAssets/assets/StringAssetInfo/value = $values/value]"/>
```

and change:

```
<xsl:template match="TitleReference[key('titleId', @id)/value = $values/value]" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="TitleReference[key('titleId', @id)//value = $values/value]" />
```

or (preferably) to:

```
<xsl:template match="TitleReference[key('titleId', @id)/assets/TitleAssets/assets/StringAssetInfo/value = $values/value]" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately i'm with XSLT 1.0 :(

Comment: Hm. Your stylesheet says `version="2.0"`. And using a variable in a match pattern, as you do in `<xsl:template match="StoryPack[value = $values]"/>`, should raise an error in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: So is your question answered then?

Comment: Unfortunately not, maybe because my real XML is more complex :  The `value` node is more deeper : xPath : /Pack/titlesPack/StoryPack/assets/TitleAssets.assets.StringAssetInfo/value  So i do :   <xsl:template match="TitleReference[key('titleId', @id.l)/assets/TitleAssets/assets/StringAssetInfo[@attrId.l = '127']/value = $values]" />

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: Please add a minimal, but representative example of your XML.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: it doesn't work in my case. It seems i don't get anything from the key()

Comment: You can see it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuP9/1

Comment: Ok, i understand why it was not working : wrong XSLT processor. I think upgrade of my IDE break the path. It's good now. Thank you !